# Wordpress meta vs taxonomy query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Usually when making Wordpress sites I use post meta only for extending custom posts, and I use custom taxonomies for basic queries. I understand why this is the correct way to use each one, that meta is more expensive than tax etc, but I never really have projects beyond this scope in WP. However I am working on one of my own ideas and I need it to run absolutely perfect and optimised from the start. I have spent hours trying to figure this one out so came on here to ask for a second opinion.

I have a post type for products and another post type for services that accept this product. So lets say a product is 20cm x 30cm x 10cm and I want to match all services that will carry this product.

I have added 3 meta fields height, width and depth. I have then got to the stage where I query the second post type and have decided that querying by post meta values is probably the wrong way to go about this? Here is an example.

```
'meta_query'=> array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => '_target_width',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_product_width', true ),
            'type' => 'numeric'

        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_target_height',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_product_height', true ),
            'type' => 'numeric'

        ),
```

Is this ok? I have my doubts and have been thinking I really need to use taxonomies instead as I am not sure about running meta queries on what could potentially be a massive amount of data.

So my question is how would you go about setting this up? If tax then how would I setup key value pairs for queries with custom taxonomies? Or do I stick to the above?

I probably could have written this a bit shorter but trying to explain in as much detail as possible.

Comment: I forgot to add to that. _target_width & height etc are also meta fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta query is probably the easiest solution, however not the optimal in terms of performance. If your `posts` and `postmeta` tables grow, this query has the potential to get very slow. That's because for each condition that you make, the database query has to make a new left join of the `postmeta` table (to load the data of this field as a separate column in the query) and this can get slow with a large table.
I've learned this the hard way trying to query the user meta in a large database with several different conditions.
As for using taxonomies - I think that the performance would be similar to the post meta query for this particular case.

So, if performance is the priority, I would recommend creating a separate database table for the services targets, that contains these columns:

```
service_id -> foreign key to the service's post ID
target_width
target_height
target_depth
```

The downside of this is that you won't be able to use the default WordPress post query methods to load the posts or store the target size, but you would have to create your custom database queries for that, so this requires some experience with mysql.

If you go with this option, you could still use post meta for the product posts unless you have to query posts by these fields (like you have to do with the services post).

So, it would definitely require a lot more work, but this solution should be much better in terms of performance.

If however creating a separate database table is not an option for you and you need to choose between using post meta and taxonomies, you would need to consider the following:

- make some predictions about how much your `postmeta` table will grow - many plugins tend to store a lot of data as post meta, so if that is your case, loading the taxonomies might be faster if the table is smaller
- using taxonomies won't be as flexible as post meta, as you'll need to create all the possible sizes as terms. Also I don't think that WordPress provides a function to run queries like `>=` with taxonomies, so you would still need to create custom DB queries to load the posts
- best way to find which one performs better is to create a database with lots of dummy data and run some benchmarks with both queries to find which one performs better. Keep in mind though that different queries would perform differently depending on the MySQL version.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Ben, after much debating I decided to go with the standard querying meta and keep an eye on performance. In hindsight I should not have done this one in Wordpress but I am thinking about future proofing it if I ever come to sell etc :)